# Incorrect string comparison

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, comparison, infinity

I have a problem i cannot figure out at all!

in my program the user enters numbers to be sorted. i had to be able to sort infinity, negative infinity and the so called "Nullity" (these i defined early in the program)

if the user wants to enter infinity for example they have to enter "Pinf" into the string.

my issue is i store the users input in a std::string and then check if the string is "pinf" or "Pinf" even tho i have entered the number 3 so the string is "3", it still goes into the if statement, what have i done wrong?!

My code is below;

```
    string Temp;
    cin>> Temp;
    if (Temp.find("Pinf")||Temp.find("pinf")) {
        Num = Pinfinity;
    }
```

It thinks the if statement is true everytime.

Comment: You are using bit `|` operator instead of logic `||` operator.

Comment: Do you mean `||` instead of `|` ? The logic is incorrect if the word(s) comes first as part of the sentence.

Comment: Apart from the incorrect operator, [read the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: Ive changed it so that it uses || instead of | and still goes into the if statement

Comment: this was solved by changing both | to || but also i HAD to use 
    `if (Temp == "Pinf" || Temp == "pinf") {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just searching for Pinf or pinf then you can use this. Note the logical or operator is `||`.

```
 if (Temp == "Pinf" || Temp == "pinf") {
```

Answer (score 2):

1.Error - you are using `|` instead of `||`.

2.Error - `find`returns

> The position of the first character of the first match. If no matches
>   were found, the function returns string::npos.
>   You should change

```
if (Temp.find("Pinf")|Temp.find("pinf")) {
```

to

```
if ((Temp.find("Pinf") != string::npos) || (Temp.find("pinf") != string::npos)) {
```

Comment: This does work however it is overkill for my simple needs of just checking if the string is "Pinf" or "pinf" i did give your answer a plus 1 however. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a bitwise or operator. Use `||` in place of `|`

```
if ( Temp.find("Pinf") != npos || Temp.find("pinf") != npos )
```

Comment: @Mahesh because if the string is not found `find()` will return npos which is not zero.

Comment: @Mahesh `if` always executes for negative values...i think you are missing something.. `if` breaks when is zero/false..